# How to send Multiple Http request sequentially in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, angular7

I have written below code to call an API each time before post request happens,
First API gets called and the second one is not getting called

```
  public post(postUrl: string, model: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.validateTokenStatus().pipe(map(response => {
        console.log('response', response);
        // if (response) {
        console.log('response2', response);
        const url = `${environment.webApiUrl}/${postUrl}`;
        this.spinnerService.start();
        console.log('response21', response);
        return this._http.post(url, model).pipe(map((res: any) => {
            console.log('response11', response);
            this.spinnerService.stop();
            return res;
        },
        error => {
            console.log('error');
            return error;
        }));
        // } else {
       // console.log('response3', response);
        // return true;
        // }
    }));
}
```

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: https://medium.com/@armno/til-combining-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-34fcbaabab40

Comment: https://medium.com/@erVikas1/how-to-keep-an-observable-returned-by-httpclient-alive-after-error-da6c5e601e9c

Comment: It would be great if you could have a look at the blogs which shows the correct way to send multiple Http request in angular, Sequentially as well as in Parallel and also how to handle the error when observable dies

Comment: You can use forkJoin for that. http://keepnote.cc/code/fork-join-example-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to do multiple async operations in a sequence after each other you usually would want to use one of mergeMap, switchMap or concatMap. Something like this could work in this situation:

```
return this.validateTokenStatus()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
        const url = `${environment.webApiUrl}/${postUrl}`;
        this.spinnerService.start();
        return this._http.post(url, model);
    }),
    map((res: any) => {
        this.spinnerService.stop();
        return res;
    })
  );
```